# Is Apache Pivot a suitable alternative to Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingx, apache-pivot

I've been taking a look at Apache Pivot and I'm wondering whether it is ready to be used as a Swing replacement (given that Swing and SwingX development goes ever so slow -- almost dormant).

Has anyone tried it out? Do you know about any drag-and-drop GUI designer for RAD with Apache Pivot?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like it depends on what you want to develop. From my reading, Pivot appears to be more in competition with Flex, Silverlight, and applets, than with desktop development.

Comment: Greetings, my hungarian-speaking friend :) Actually, what I'm curious about is if Apache Pivot can be used as a drop-in replacement for Swing for use in Desktop applications. Since I read that it can be done with JavaFX too, I very curious about hearing if anyone has been using Pivot as a GUI toolkit for desktop applications...

Comment: nothing and nobody dormant in the SwingX realm. It's open source, so if you think it should move at a quicker pace - feel free to contribute :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I'm ever so happy to hear that (and to hear it from the legendary kleopatra herself! You're quite a celebrity when swing[x] is the topic!); unfortunately, I'm not skilled enough to contribute to the project... Sorry if me saying that it goes too slow was inappropriate, I didn't mean any disrespect: I still see SwingX as a amazingly powerful extension to the Swing graphical toolkit. I'm just in a phase where I'm evaluating alternatives,just to be up-to-date

Comment: Have you considered SWT?

Comment: @Marcelo I need UI to look exactly the same on all platforms and, as far as I know, SWT relies on the underlying OS APIs to render its [heavyweight?] components, with a platform-dependent look...

Comment: @user1178114 Indeed, SWT relies on the OS to render the components and it looks (a bit) different on every OS. Looks better than Swing though, IMO, but if you *really* need it to be exactly the same (may I ask why?) its probably not an option.

Comment: @Marcelo Simply because it's a company policy I've no control upon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache Pivot is not a good tool to create GUIs. I've tried it and I've spent several hours persisting in it's potential that is said, however, finally I built the interface from scratch without any tools.

I would like to suggest WindowBuilder. I sucessfuly worked with it, in another, huge, desktop software. Sure this is my opinion, but I have some experience in building GUIs, specially in Swing. Just to be clear, I am not affiliated with the software, and this is not an advertisment, this tool simply works!

Comment: About my answer above, I'm aware that WindowBuilder uses Swing SDK, and makes easier the work with it, instead of providing another SDK. But that is the point, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to create a good desktop GUI with Apache Pivot.  Of course, I'm coming to Pivot almost a year after Lincoln Pompermaier, so I'm sure Pivot has improved.

Apache Pivot needs a good tutorial so that people will understand how to use it.  Since Pivot is open source, I might just write that tutorial myself.

I've never used a GUI builder.  I wrote all of my Swing GUIs by hand, and I'll probably write all of my Pivot GUIs by hand.